# Error in terminal after installation of MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

```
W: GPG error: http://ftp.wa.co.za trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CBCB082A1BB943DB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-deb-files/) might help.

It needs a public key to continue.

Comment: Thanks simon, followed the instructions on the link and they worked.